# 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'status' Error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
responseString = {"status":"success","data":{"text":"Say Hello to\n\nAfrica’sfil’SI\nAnonymous\n\nSocial Network\nFrom Great Ho\nMitt\/6.6om","progress":100}}

dynamic jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
            Debug.WriteLine(jsonDe.data);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your responseString is supposed to be String ? or this is your real code?

Comment: Can you clear the dll from GAC and let us know if this resolve the issue. This is the most common cause for this kind of error.

Comment: What dll am I to clear? @Jaco

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` takes a string argument, you are passing it an object.

Comment: Unless @Ninjakannon suggestion resolves the issues, you should remove Newtonsoft.Json.dll from the GAC.

Comment: @Jaco there is no Newtonsoft.Json.dll in my GAC.

Comment: @Ninjakannon still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

finally, This worked for me:

```
public class  responseData 
{
  public string status { get; set; }
  public dataClass data { get; set; }

}

public class dataClass 
{
public string text { get; set; }
public string progress { get; set; }
}
string myjsonstring = responseString;
            responseData jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<responseData>(myjsonstring);
            Debug.WriteLine(jsonDe.data.progress); // Outputs 100
            Debug.WriteLine(jsonDe.status); // Outputs success
```